# React-csv is not working inside react-bootstrap dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dom, drop-down-menu, download

I have a business need which is as shown below
[image]

here i have used DropdownButton from react bootstrap to achive the above menu

```
<span className="widget-controls" mr-eye-widget-type='Menu'>
                    <DropdownButton
                        alignRight
                        drop='down'
                        title="" className="download-CSV-button fa fa-ellipsis-v ">
                        <Dropdown.Item>Testttt</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item>
                            <CSVLink { ... switchRef } data={this.state.downloadData} asyncOnClick={true} headers={this.state.dowloadHeader} filename={this.state.downloaFileName}>
                                <span className="csv-download" mr-eye-widget-type='DownloadButton' >
                                    <div className="fa fa-download listColor" >
                                        <span className="download-text">{widgetLabelConfig.englishConfig.Resource_Download_as_CSV}
                                        </span></div>
                                </span>
                            </CSVLink>
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                    </DropdownButton>
                </span>
```

and also here in the code one of the menu item is ***Testttt*** which is displaying where as second menu item has ***CSVLink*** which is a npm react-csv module for download this will not be render in the dom when i put it outside drop menu it works fine please let me know why is it failing when it is inside DropdownButton

Comment: I guess dropdown menu item select callback stopping propagation and prevents calling of on click callback of csv download link.

Comment: not sure can u please let me know how to fix this yes may be

Comment: Im not very familiar with this component but i think your dropdown items are `<a>` but there is a prop that you can set as button for dropdown items **as** like `<Dropdown.Item as="button">...</Dropdown.item>`

Comment: ossom thank u that is solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the dropdown item is a clickable hyperlink in your case, you can set the prop `as` as `"button"` from the `Dropdown.Item` like this:

```
<Dropdown.Item as="button">
    .......
</Dropdown.Item>
```